# share() operator not working for Observable in Rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-kotlin2

I have a scenario where we i have an emmiter which constantly emits data like this

```
fun subscribeForEvents(): Flowable<InkChannel> {
    return Flowable.create<InkChannel>({
        if (inkDevice.availableDeviceServices.contains(DeviceServiceType.EVENT_DEVICE_SERVICE)) {
            (inkDevice.getDeviceService(DeviceServiceType.EVENT_DEVICE_SERVICE) as EventDeviceService).subscribe(object : EventCallback {
                override fun onUserActionExpected(p0: UserAction?) {
                    it.onNext(InkChannel.UserActionEvent(p0))
                }

                override fun onEvent(p0: InkDeviceEvent?, p1: Any?) {
                    it.onNext(InkChannel.InkEvents<Any>(p0, p1))
                }

                override fun onUserActionCompleted(p0: UserAction?, p1: Boolean) {

                }
            }

            )
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER).share()

}
```

now i have a service which i start on application launch and listen to it

```
  inkDeviceBus.subscribeForEvents()
                .filter { it -> (it as InkChannel.InkEvents<*>).event == InkDeviceEvent.STATUS_CHANGED }
                .map { it -> it as InkChannel.InkEvents<*> }
                .map { it -> it.value.toString() }
                .filter { value -> value == "CONNECTED" || value == "DISCONNECTED" }
                .map { it -> it == "CONNECTED" }
                .subscribeBy { b ->
                    if (b) stopSelf()
                }
```

I have another activity MainActivity which is called upon launch where i observe the same event.
Now the issue is only the listener in the service gets the events and the activity is not receiving any events.

Now when i remove the listener form the service then activity starts receiving events. I have used the operator **share** for sharing the observable but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.share()` only affects the instance it is called on. Since each call to `subscribeForEvents` creates a new instance the `.share()` does not change the behavior.

You need to call `subscribeForEvents` once and then use the returned value when you want to receive the events. As long as the same object is used it will share the underlying listener.